# Magento | How to add Save Action for Customer Group new field

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php

I added a new field for Customer Group. It called customer group email. 
I added the field and it displays in the backend but it doesn't save the data and I don't know How can I add Save action. I tried to add this code in the file that called

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php

```
$groupEmail = $this->getRequest()->getParam('groupemail');
$customerGroup->setData($groupEmail)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

The added code in Form.php is:

```
$groupEmail = $fieldset->addField('customer_group_email', 'text',
    array(
        'name'  => 'groupemail',
        'label' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group email'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group email'),
        'note'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Maximum length must be less then %s symbols', Mage_Customer_Model_Group::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH),
        'class' => $validateClass,
        'required' => true,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

At first, you need create database column to store email addresses:

```
ALTER TABLE `customer_group` ADD `groupemail` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I do not advice to change core files, so the best way - creation of a new extension and listening the `customer_group_save_before` event to set email from a request, but you can modify this file:

> Magento_root/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/GroupController.php

and add the following code to the `saveAction` function:

```
$groupEmail = $this->getRequest()->getParam('groupemail');
$customerGroup->setGroupemail($groupEmail);
```

after the following code:

```
if (!empty($customerGroupCode)) {
    $customerGroup->setCode($customerGroupCode);
}
```

Comment: I need to send a copy of the invoice email to customer group email when a customer form customer group placed an order.